# Error while importing this build

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I uploaded a build to iTunes connect. When the processing gets completed, it shows the error,

> 'There was an error importing this build.'

I know this question has been asked before, but their solutions don't help me out. So I'm asking this question.

I have tried disabling bitcode. But it didn't work

For reference

[image: See the error in this image]

Comment: What is xcode version you are using? Can you try with Application Loader once? ( Disable bitcode as well )

Comment: @AmodGokhale I tried using Application Loader. But same error appeared. I am using xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution.

Actually the issue was, I had GooglePlus library in my framework folder. I wasn't using it but it was there. Which not allowing the binary to be thinned. I just had to remove the GooglePlus library and it worked!!